# Jekyll и глобальные объекты, как задавать свои?

Tags: jekyll

Например, мне хочется создать сайт-галерею с использованием Jekyll, где будут вымещаться квадратные картинки (по примеру artstation.com).
И картинки эти будут находиться в отдельной папке imgs, например, не суть важно.
Будут браться и выводиться новые при генерации сайта, если вдруг добавляется новая в эту директорию.
Вот как тут, например, добавляются тайтлы со временем постов в артикал по постам:

```
 {% for post in site.posts %}
        <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" 
        title="{{ post.title }}">
        {{ post.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
```

Всё вроде нормально.
Но Jekyll блогоориентированный сборщик статических сайтов, а речь идет о картинках. Да и вообще мой вопрос о функционале.
Разве нельзя написать так:

```
</ul>
    {% for img in site.imgs %}
            <li><img href="{{ img.url }}" ></li>
          {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Таким образом будет объект изображения для каждого изображения, из которого можно брать url и использовать.

Наверняка тут понаписана полнейшая чуть со всех точек зрения, но это лишь подтверждает, что я нифига не понял как работает Liquid в Jekyll.
Официальную документацию прочитал на сайте Liquid, то же самое и с jekyll, но не понял до конца этот момент.
То есть можно использовать  только объекты post (ссылка на пост), page (ссылка на текущую страницу), переменные через "site."(глобальные переменные, которые определены в _config.yml) и всё?
Как это изменить, например?